Could not contact service /controller_manager/load_controller error
I have been trying to run a gazebo simulation package from ros2 humble, with gazebo11. This is my console output:
root@Amk:/opt/ros/humble/src# ros2 launch gazebo_simulation robot_sim.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /root/.ros/log/2024-05-13-16-17-14-721463-Amk-30682
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
urdf_file_name : rs_robot.urdf
urdf_file_name : rs_robot.urdf
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [30683]
[INFO] [gzclient-2]: process started with pid [30685]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [30687]
[INFO] [joy_node-4]: process started with pid [30689]
[INFO] [robot_control.py-5]: process started with pid [30691]
[INFO] [ros2-6]: process started with pid [30693]
[INFO] [ros2-7]: process started with pid [30695]
[INFO] [ros2-8]: process started with pid [30697]
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1715606235.747670906] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1715606235.747818095] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1715606235.747826952] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment fl_steering_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1715606235.747832363] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment fl_wheel_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1715606235.747837322] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment fr_steering_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1715606235.747842261] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment fr_wheel_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1715606235.747846870] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment rl_steering_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1715606235.747851679] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment rl_wheel_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1715606235.747856559] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment rr_steering_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1715606235.747861127] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment rr_wheel_link
[gzserver-1] ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1032:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
[gzserver-1] AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1715606236.607369090] [four_ws_robot_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [fl_wheel_joint]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1715606236.607762918] [four_ws_robot_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [fr_wheel_joint]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1715606236.607775272] [four_ws_robot_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [rl_wheel_joint]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1715606236.607781303] [four_ws_robot_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [rr_wheel_joint]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1715606236.607786403] [four_ws_robot_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [fl_steering_joint]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1715606236.607791763] [four_ws_robot_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [fr_steering_joint]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1715606236.607796913] [four_ws_robot_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [rl_steering_joint]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1715606236.607801932] [four_ws_robot_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [rr_steering_joint]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1715606236.626811874] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading gazebo_ros2_control plugin
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1715606236.633503763] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in namespace: /
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1715606236.633555051] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in ros 2 node: gazebo_ros2_control
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1715606236.638092956] [gazebo_ros2_control]: connected to service!! robot_state_publisher
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1715606236.638727081] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Received urdf from param server, parsing...
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1715606236.638785302] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading parameter files /home/robotmania/four_ws_ros2/install/gazebo_simulation/share/gazebo_simulation/models/rs_robot/config/controllers.yaml
[gzserver-1] [ERROR] [1715606236.638897806] [gazebo_ros2_control]: parser error Couldn't parse params file: '--params-file /home/robotmania/four_ws_ros2/install/gazebo_simulation/share/gazebo_simulation/models/rs_robot/config/controllers.yaml'. Error: Error opening YAML file, at ./src/parser.c:270, at ./src/rcl/arguments.c:406
[gzserver-1] 
[joy_node-4] [INFO] [1715606236.894302767] [joy_node]: Opened joystick: Microntek USB Joystick.  deadzone: 0.050000
[gzclient-2] 
[gzclient-2] (gzclient:30685): dconf-WARNING **: 16:17:18.067: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
[gzclient-2] 
[gzclient-2] (gzclient:30685): dconf-WARNING **: 16:17:18.067: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
[gzclient-2] 
[gzclient-2] (gzclient:30685): dconf-WARNING **: 16:17:18.068: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
[gzclient-2] 
[gzclient-2] (gzclient:30685): dconf-WARNING **: 16:17:18.068: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
[gzclient-2] 
[gzclient-2] (gzclient:30685): dconf-WARNING **: 16:17:18.068: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
[ros2-7] Could not contact service /controller_manager/load_controller
[ros2-6] Could not contact service /controller_manager/load_controller
[ros2-8] Could not contact service /controller_manager/load_controller
[ERROR] [ros2-7]: process has died [pid 30695, exit code 1, cmd 'ros2 control load_controller --set-state active forward_velocity_controller'].
[ERROR] [ros2-6]: process has died [pid 30693, exit code 1, cmd 'ros2 control load_controller --set-state active forward_position_controller'].
[ERROR] [ros2-8]: process has died [pid 30697, exit code 1, cmd 'ros2 control load_controller --set-state active joint_state_broadcaster'].



After gazebo is opened, and the urdf is loaded, I cant use the connected PS2 gamepad to control the rover, I have tested the gamepad using "ros2 run joy joy_node" and "ros2 topic echo /joy", all gamepad's buttons are functional

Which ROS distro are you using? Can you run the gazebo_ros2_control_demos?

@ChristophFroehlich yes, I was able to run all of them, including the 9th one that involves gazebo, no issues, the error I am getting is related to the controls, I was just able to open the animation and I have edited the question at the bottom for more context

Have a look at the given error message
[gzserver-1] [ERROR] [1715606236.638897806] [gazebo_ros2_control]: parser error Couldn't parse params file: '--params-file /home/robotmania/four_ws_ros2/install/gazebo_simulation/share/gazebo_simulation/models/rs_robot/config/controllers.yaml'. Error: Error opening YAML file, at ./src/parser.c:270, at ./src/rcl/arguments.c:406

This is the root cause. Check if the file exists and if it has proper yaml syntax.

I forgot to change a path in the yaml file which was leading to this error, thank you
